# Android Studio (Mac) — проблема с поддержкой Wear

Tags: android-studio, android-wear

Пробую работать с Android Studio на Mac (студия 2.3.3 Build #AI-16, macOS 10.12.6). Создаю обычный проект для Android начиная с 5-го — всё нормально. Но мне нужно добавить функциональность Wear — на этом начинаются проблемы (как если создавать проект сразу с поддержкой Wear, так и если добавлять модуль позже, в уже рабочий проект).

В Gradle Sync пишется

> Install Repository and sync project, а в Gradle Build: Could not
>   resolve all depencies for configuration ':mobile:_debugApk' и Could
>   not resolve all depencies for configuration ':wear:_debugApkCopy'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все советы, которые нашёл здесь, пробовал: переинсталляция API, полное удаление (с удалением кэша, проектов, настроек и т.п.) Android Studio и установка с нуля — ничего не помогает. Если кликнуть на Install Repository and sync project — ничего не происходит. Ручная синхронизация тоже не помогает.

Честно, уже не знаю, в какую сторону копать... Несколько дней вожусь с этой ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support library начиная с версии 26 находится только в гугловом maven репозитории, в корневом build.gradle должно быть:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // Если используется Gradle 4.0+
        google()
        // Если используется Gradle < 4.0
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

PS: также можно просто откатить версию на 25.4.0